# How to set xss security in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, xss

In My Spring Boot Project I have implemented this method in a configuration class to configure Xss protection.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().xssProtection().and().contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'");
}
```

But, when I am trying to test the contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'") blocks my scripts online. How can i do to solve this problem in order keep good XSS protection???

Comment: Are your scripts served by the same origin? What error does the  console show?